# Top constraint to SuperView.top under Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to get full screen height including status bar within my `ViewController` whose parent is `Navigation Controller` (with no `Navigation Bar`). The `ViewController` contains a `ScrollView` (with red background) and it's content view (with green background). Without `Navigation Controller`, it works as expected. Here's how it looks like:

[image]

However, as soon as I add `Navigation Controller` as parent, it looks like:

[image]

Here are my AutoLayout constraints:

[image]

Comment: What are the values for those constraints, if its a 0 for the SuperView why don't u try to set it for -18 for example or an equivalent value to cover the status bar ?

Comment: @Yaman I tried the same trick. It works and covers the status bar area. But it keeps content view scrollable which I don't want. The only reason I've added scroll view is to scroll entire view when keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to replicate you scene and tested in iOS 9.  Not facing the issue you mentioned. I do not see red colour any where. Here is the storyboard.

[Storyboard](http://www.dropbox.com/s/1enetg3w1zqt2uc/Main.storyboard?dl=0)

Even if you still get this issue for other reasons, you can,
As mentioned by Yaman you can change the top constraint with constant -20, to make scroll view go under the status bar and cover the whole screen. Then if you want, you can set the `UIScrollView` `contentInset` property to make its top to move 20 points down.

```
scrollView.contentInset.top = 20
```

This will make scrollable content shift 20 points below the top edge of scroll.

Comment: That works. However, I used baseScrollViewer.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero. That way my interface builder looks the same as expected.